# Animation for 2 layout with combination of many animation

Tags: android, animation

I have 2 layouts say 1 and 2. 2nd layout is behind 1st layout. I want to animate following way

> 1 to go up at same time 2nd to go down then 1 will go back and 2nd 
>   will go front and now 1st will come down at same time 2nd will come up . 
>   so now 1 is behind 2nd layout ..

[image]

Comment: What have you tried till now? Maybe its just me but, your explanation isn't much clear.

Comment: as of now i just scal up and down but taht too viva xml i want to do viva code as der are 2-3 animation